# Android - Firebase Debug SHA1 certificate

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement `Firebase Auth` with Google Sign In. While adding the android app under my project, it asks me for a `Debug signing certificate SHA-1`. Now, this project is shared with my team mates and everybody will be running the app through their respective Android Studio software. My queries are:

1. The debug key is going to be different for all of us. Should I be adding SHA1 debug certificate keys of all of my team mates under the Firebase Project Settings? I currently have only mine under it and the other person who ran the app code through their Android Studio couldn't not use Google Sign in on their phone. The signin process would just stop abruptly.
2. Once the app is ready for production, the the app would be distributed through play store. Is there a possibility of them facing problems when they download the app? I'm curious since all their devices will have different keys again.

Comment: You can read this to better understand how the app sign in works https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: @Ymmanuel thanks for the link. What about release mode SHA1 key? Should that be listed in the Firebase Project Settings as well?

Comment: hi, I m also facing similar issue. I made app with debug sha1 key and now after publishing I did not change any key and user is not able to login using google account. do I need to get new key from keystore I created for signing apk. pls guide. I have integrated google drive to my app

Comment: @Panache did you add release SHA1 in your project?

Answer (score 6):

You can add as many debug SHA-1 keys as you want in the Project Settings for each of your development machines. Before you publish your app, the release SHA-1 key needs to be uploaded in Project Settings. Each of the apps that users download from the Play Store is signed with the same release key, so it should not be a problem!

Comment: When i setup my Firebase project, I didn't put in my Debug SHA1, how can I add it after the fact?

Comment: But what if all the members debug SHA-1 keys are same?
Because, my firebase project works fine on my machine and it doesn't work on any other member's machine :(
Please fine question regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561231/firebase-phone-authentication-in-android-same-code-doesnt-work-on-different-m)