# Firebase phone authentication in android - same code doesn't work on different machines

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have integrated **Firebase phone authentication** in my android project.

For this I have followed all the steps given in [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) link.

All works fine on my machine, Also I pushed this code to git.

Now when another user pulls that code, it doesn't work on his machine.

Error he is getting is -

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed ]
```

I have searhed for this error, but everywhere I found is -

1. Put your SHA1 key
2. Enable "phone authentication" in authentication
   tab in your firebase project.

But I have already done that and all works fine on my machine. But doesn't work on another user's machine. Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you should add the SHA1 debug certificate keys of all your team members from git manually unless it's a released build. You can add as many debug SHA-1 keys as you want in the [Project Settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/) from `firebase` console  for every member's development machines.

[image]

**Alternative:** Share your keystore file to all of them.

Comment: I added SHA1 debug certificate keys of all my team members on firebase project.